# IPython.display clear_output not working in Microsoft Azure Synapse Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, azure-synapse, ipywidgets

I'm trying to set up a dropdown widget with ipywidgets, IPython.display on a notebook on the Microsoft Azure Synapse platform.

Even with simple code I get this error message:

`JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "clear_output" to type 'Microsoft.Analytics.SynapseNotebookExecService.Models.Message.MessageType'. Path 'header.msg_type', line 1, position 89.

--> ArgumentException: Requested value 'clear_output' was not found.`

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

```
from ipywidgets import widgets 
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=[('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)],
    value=2,
    description='Number:',
)
display(dropdown)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can see the dropdown options when running the cell but still I can't get the whole logic working: change selection, filter a dataframe, display the filtered dataframe. The same error return. I also tried the code in the example at this [link on the ipywidgets doc](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.6.2/examples/Widget%20Events.html) but when I click the button after running the cell, doesn't return anything.